# Initializing fields in structs from variables

Tags: c, struct, c-preprocessor

I am trying to to initialize fields in structs from constant values handed in through variables.

```
typedef struct _A{
    uint a;
}A;
const A a = {9} ; const A b = { .a = 10 }; const A c = {0};

typedef struct _Z{
    A a;
    A b;
    A c;
}Z;
Z z = { a,b,c };
```

but this yields the Compiler error : `initializer element is not constant`
what is not that obvious because a,b and c are declared as const an should not be modifiable at runtime.

what I would want to get in memory is something like :

```
0x00 9
0x04 10
0x08 0
```

because the struct is just an integer array.

now the question is how can I tell the compiler (using arm-none-eabi-gcc) that the variables `a`,`b` and `c` are used like defines and can/should be replaced by their contents since the only a reference to `z` will be present in the running program?
Maybe some pragma or even a preprocessor directive?

I am constructing `A` in the same Macro in which I initialize `a`. looking like this but somewhat more complex.

```
#define bar(name, ...)\
typedef struct __bar_##name{\
    List(applydef, __VA_ARGS__)\
}bar_##name;\
const bar_##name name ={List(applyset, __VA_ARGS__)};
bar(foobar, a,b)
```

The code above was self expanded due to excessive use of defines.
Another solution I would accept here would be to not generate a new struct but a new define I can the throw into the macro looking like this.

Comment: Is it c or c++? it's different.

Comment: Please choose a language. `{ .a = 10 }` isn't standard C++.

Comment: it is not possible in c++?

Comment: `initializer element is not constant` because `z` is Global(static) variables.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In the case of local automatic variable this message is not displayed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit see [this](http://ideone.com/cCmwVq), and [this](http://ideone.com/HOauCK).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: You're right; my Coliru post was mistakenly using C++.

Comment: Do you really need the intermediate objects `a`, `b` and `c`, perhaps as a kind of constant values? Otherwise, you could just initialise `z` directly as `{{9}, {10}, {0}}`. Or is that too simple?

Comment: i was inteding it to wrap up the usb identification structures and there i have to pack generate a byte stream from a config containing interfaces where each of these interfaces contains endpoints and the number of interfaces and endpoints can vary from one interface to an other making it impossible to handle by just one struct.

Comment: Quote: "how can i tell the compiler (using arm-none-eabi-gcc) that the variables a,b and c are used like defines and can/should be replaced by their contents" Obviously you could rewrite your variables as #defines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialiser `{a,b,c}` is unfortunately not constant, but your declaration of `z` requires it to be.

> `[C99: 6.6/7]:` More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers. Such a constant expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the following:
>
> - an arithmetic constant expression,
> - a null pointer constant,
> - an address constant, or
> - an address constant for an object type plus or minus an integer constant expression.
>
> `[C99: 6.7.8/4]:` All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

`z` has static storage duration because you declared it at global scope. If you moved its declaration into a function then this rule would not apply.

None of the names `a`, `b` or `c` qualify as constant expressions, despite your use of `const`:

> `[C99: 6.6/8]:` An *arithmetic constant expression* shall have arithmetic type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, floating constants, enumeration constants, character constants, and `sizeof` expressions. Cast operators in an arithmetic constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to arithmetic types, except as part of an operand to a `sizeof` operator whose result is an integer constant.

Although `struct _S` merely wraps a `uint`, that doesn't mean it *is* a `uint`. Indeed, regarding `struct _Z`, your assertion that *"the struct is just an integer array"* is wrong: you fail to consider types.

C++ is substantially more lax than C in this regard, especially in the era of `constexpr`.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you (other than moving the initialisation), but this is the cause.

Comment: thank you very much, i was expecting that it is not possible.